# Regex and jQuery to select "(xy)" where x and y are any letters

Tags: jquery, regex

What would be the Javascript/jQuery regular expression to select instances of "(xy)" where x and y are any letters of the alphabet ? Example : (en), (fr), (es).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/\([a-z][a-z]\)/
```

or

```
/\([a-z]{2}\)/
```

Comment: Or `[a-zA-Z]` if you want upper and lower case

Comment: Or just `[A-z]` for the same effect

Comment: @st3inn: No; ranges in character-classes use ASCII order, so `[A-z]` would mean "an uppercase letter `A-Z`, a left square bracket, a backslash, a right square bracket, a circumflex, an underscore, a backquote, or a lowercase letter `a-z`".

Answer (score 1):

Would be something like

```
"\([a-z]{2}\)"
```

Comment: You were right the first time; if you create your regex from a string literal, then you do need to double the backslash, because `"\([a-z]{2}\)"` is equivalent to `"([a-z]{2})"`. (But I think it's better to avoid the issue entirely, by not creating your regex from a string literal.)